# why it gives me>> com.android.volley.Timeout Error << when i click register button, while it supposed to add new record in the database

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using Volley library to pass the parameters to `VolleyRegister.php`
and this the functions in `ActivityMain.java`:

```
private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}},
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            return params;}};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);}
```

And the error when I click the register button:

> com.android.volley.Timeout Error

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        5000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```